# What does "the world's strongest currency" title mean for investors?

Tags: currency, investment

Kuwaiti Dinar shows up as the most expensive in the world. Does that mean I better invest in KWD (or the safe USD) instead of my home currency (IDR)?

A little background: I am just an ordinary person without economics / finance background and hope to learn from the experts here. My home currency never fails to show up in the top 5 least valuable currencies in the world. Economic crises that come too often and stay too long make me wonder if I make the right decision to put all of my retirement savings in local equity mutual funds.

Comment: As @ramazan pointed out this should not affect your savings decisions at all. If you are interested in making better personal finance decisions you should consider having a look at money.stackexchange.com. Economics mostly deals with economic theory, Money deals with personal finances.

Comment: "most expensive" or "strongest" by what standard? Without that information it's not a meaningful question.

Comment: The original poster is already confused, which is why the question is posted. One can, and did, what might have been meant by the word strongest by going to google to understand why the OP is confused. So, valid question in my perspective.

Comment: Being confused isn't a sufficient condition for a question to be valid. IMO, a _good_ SE question involves some research on the asker's part to try and provide a precise question for others to answer. On a probably related note, I'm not sure I would consider "How should I invest" type question on topic here (it may be on topic on Money.SE but I'm not familiar with their conventions), but that is something we should decide as a community in meta and I'm happy to abide by what is decided there.

Comment: One might agree/disagree with some of the assertions put forward by @cc7768 but then one starts thinking that the whole discussion does not add much to the world on the other side of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strong currency understanding in your question does not have any interpretation that would be an economic factor that should effect investment, or any other decision. It is merely units.

It answers the question of '1 US dollar buys least of which currency?'. It also answers the question of '1 Colombian peso buys least of which currency?', or any other benchmark currency of your choice.

The Kuwait government could say that they decided to replace KWD by KWD2 and 1 KWD would equal 1000 KWD2. Then everything that has a price of $x$ KWD would now have a price of $1000x$ KWD2. Now, your US dollar would buy a lot of KWD2, but your investment decision would not be effected by this change because there has been only a change in units, and no other intrinsic differences.